HttpOnly cookies not being attached to request
My app uses JWT set as httpOnly cookie. It's working great while using app with various wallet types, but it's not working while using Safe. The problem is that even though cookie was set in client, while App is opened through Safe UI, cookie is not attached to any requests and therefore I'm getting 401 on my API requests. Any suggestions how to deal with it?
